# How to subclass a window in Windows? (using Go)

Tags: windows, go, subclass

I want to sub-class the actual window to detect when its size has changed.

This is the code relevant where I've tried to subclassing it, using CallWindowProcW and SetWindowLongW, but it does not show any message when I maximize the window, so I'm supposed I've set wrongly some of those procedures. How to do it?

```
var oldWindowProc uintptr

func windowProc(hwnd syscall.Handle, msg uint32, wparam, lparam uintptr) (rc uintptr) {
    switch msg {
    case WM_SIZE:
        fmt.Println("Size")
        if wparam == SIZE_MAXIMIZED {
            fmt.Println("Changed!")
        }
    default:
        return CallWindowProcW(oldWindowProc, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam)
    }
    return 0
}

func main() {
    oldWindowProc, _ = SetWindowLongW(syscall.Stdin, GWLP_WNDPROC,
        syscall.NewCallback(windowProc))

    for {

    }
}
```

Comment: Go doesn't have classes or subclassing

Comment: It is to subclass a Windows' window

Comment: No. Go does not have classes or subclasses. Therefore, your question makes no sense.

Comment: The question is: How to subclass a window in Windows? (using Go)
So it makes sense

Comment: It doesn't seem like the term "subclassing" would be appropriate here since really what this appears to do is to replace a callback for the window with another one that happens to call the original callback. Not really subclassing.

Comment: It is so in Windows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#subclassing_window

Comment: I don't know Go but I do know a bug when I see one.  Stdin is an abstraction of a *stream* in many platforms.  Usually connected to the keyboard, it can often be redirected.  It is *never* a window.

Comment: godoc syscall Stdin => Stdin  = getStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)

Comment: Subclassing is the term by Microsoft. See for example SetWindowSubclass API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about winapi, but it seems your code [closely resembles an example](http://neolit123.blogspot.com/2012/06/first-impressions-on-go-programming.html#hcon) of [`go-winapi` wrapper](https://github.com/lxn/go-winapi)

And using that wrapper lib, this modified version seems to work for me:

([Full code](http://pastebin.com/MY8Q9Tpu))

*snip*

```go
// window procedure
func WndProc(hwnd winapi.HWND, msg uint32, wparam uintptr, lparam uintptr) uintptr {
    switch msg {
    case winapi.WM_SIZE:
        if wparam == SIZE_MAXIMIZED {
            fmt.Println("Changed!")
        }
    }
    // call original procedure
    return winapi.CallWindowProc(uintptr(oldWndProc), hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam)
}
```

I am sure you could look at that wrapper lib and derive the more direct way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks! I could not find any example related.

Answer (score 0):

You code says:

SetWindowLongW(syscall.Stdin, GWLP_WNDPROC, syscall.NewCallback(windowProc))

But why are you passing syscall.Stdin to SetWindowLongW? Aren't you suppose to supply window handle instead?

Alex

Comment: syscall.Stdin is a handle. Stdin = getStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)

Comment: According to SetWindowLong documentation, first hWnd parameter is "A handle to the window and, indirectly, the class to which the window belongs". If you want to "subclass" a particular window, you must pass its handle to SetWindowLong, not syscall.Stdin